# how to set dataType jsonp in ajax.BeginForm in asp mvc 5

Tags: types, jsonp, ajax.beginform

i want set dataType jsonp in ajax.BeginForm
for example
this current code

```
Url = "/api/Phrase/Create",
OnSuccess = "OnSuccess(data)",
OnFailure = "OnFailure",
HttpMethod="POST"
```

change to

```
Url = "/api/v3/Phrase/Create",
OnSuccess = "OnSuccess(data)",
OnFailure = "OnFailure",
HttpMethod= "POST",
dataType= "jsonp"
```

like in jquery :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/v3/Phrase/Create",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
});
```

if you can help Please replay to this request
else Should do something
thanks all